# How to get rid of touchpad notification?

Tags: touchpad, 18.04, notification, surface

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Surface Pro 2, and nearly everything works out of the box.

But: the single most annoying thing is a notification about something not working with the touchpad. It appears most of the time I click on left or right touchpad button.

This is the notification. It's being displayed for 2 seconds.

[image: touchpad-problem]

With 16.04, a similar notification was shown as one of those bubbles in the upper right corner, it wasn't that much in the way then. 
In fact the touchpad is working mostly. Right click doesn't work in shell. Hä?

Does anybody have an idea how to get rid of this, or better still, make the touchpad work?
Thank you.

Comment: Actually this is a duplicate - exactly the same as the situation described there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/980886/trackpad-button-click-drag-doesnt-work-sends-key-event-surface-pro2-ubunt]

Answer (score 0):

After not finding a solution for months, I installed elementary OS. There is an option to disable notification bubbles altogether.